# Loop Function on Mouseover in Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I am trying to create a carousel of images and wanted to horizontal scroll when the user hovers over the left and right side of the div. I have two "invisible" divs for the left and right controls and gave them eventListeners:

**right.addEventListener("mouseover", goRight)**

```
function goRight() {
    document.getElementById('images').scrollLeft += 20;
}
```

**left.addEventListener("mouseover", goLeft)**

```
function goLeft() {

    document.getElementById('images').scrollLeft -= 20;
}
```

When I hover over them, it will scroll once, but I would like it to continuously scroll until I mouseout. How I can I make goRight()/goLeft() loop while I am hovering on the controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the `setInterval()` method which should be cancelled on `mouseout`. You can store the interval id and use `clearInterval()` on `mouseout`:

```js
const delay = 100;
let intervalId;

function goLeft() {
  intervalId = setInterval(
    () => (document.getElementById('images').scrollLeft -= 20),
    delay,
  );
}

function goRight() {
  intervalId = setInterval(
    () => (document.getElementById('images').scrollLeft += 20),
    delay,
  );
}

function stopScrolling() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}

left.addEventListener('mouseover', goLeft);
left.addEventListener('mouseout', stopScrolling);
right.addEventListener('mouseover', goRight);
right.addEventListener('mouseout', stopScrolling);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! This was exactly what I was looking for. Didn't think about using setInterval smh

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Boolean that will be 'true' when the user has his mouse over the element.

```
// for the right side:
let mouseOverRight = false;


right.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
    mouseOverRight = true;
});
right.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
    mouseOverRight = false;
});
```

Then using an interval, change the delay to whatever speed you want

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  if (mouseOverRight)
  /// Scroll logic here
}, 300);
```

Then of course you would have to do the same for the left side.